# Why font in Firefox not applying(however it is in console)?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have this strange situation: browser says, that element using Helvetica Neue, but it didn't look as it should.

Here is text from Chrome:

[image]

and how it look in Firefox:

[image] 


but in console it show me that it is using Helvetica:

[image]

HTML:

```
  <div class="span5 overview_text">
   <ul>
  <li> &mdash;  Offseting the environmental damange caused by printing.</li>
  <li> &mdash;  An additional independent ravenue source.</li>
  <li> &mdash;  Maximum explosure. Highest Click-through-rates.</li>
  <li> &mdash;  Simple & Quick HTML code embedding.</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .overview_text{
line-height: 1.5;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica; 
}
```

Why it is happening ?

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the question here. Is the problem here that Chrome is missing a sentence? Or is the problem here that your font isn't working.
Also, can you have some of your main HTML code to post here?

Comment: No, I just cut it badly for Chrome. Font is not applying in Firefox, but console says that it is Helvetica font.Addiing HTML.

Comment: Yet another silly question, but you're not using the `<font>` tag are you?

Comment: No. I showed my css that I'm using.

Comment: @MID, you did not show all the relevant parts of your HTML and CSS. There is apparently at least something that sets the font size. But does your system actually have Helvetica or Helvetica Neue? To me, it seems that the two browsers are displaying Arial in two slightly different font sizes, possibly depending on CSS settings interpreted or implemented differently.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your not overriding the CSS font options with your advanced font settings in Firefox (see image). Specifically ensure the "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above" box is checked in advanced.

[image: Firefox Advanced Font Options]